# trying to scrape a table from web using selenium in python. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table from web using selenium in python. But it shows the error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'**. It is a form type web page and the table has no class. So how can I modify the code to scrape the data?

````
from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 

# Web page url 
driver.get("http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic_work_details.aspx?page=S&lflag=eng&state_name=KERALA&state_code=16&fin_year=2020-2021&source=national&Digest=s5wXOIOkT98cNVkcwF6NQA") 
  
# Find District of option 
x = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_dist') 
drop = Select(x) 
  
# Select by value 
drop.select_by_value("1613") 
time.sleep(4) 

# Find Block of option 
x = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_blk') 
drop = Select(x) 
  
# Select by value 
drop.select_by_value("1613001") 
time.sleep(4) 

# Find GP of option 
x = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_pan') 
drop = Select(x) 
  
# Select by value 
drop.select_by_value("1613001001") 
time.sleep(4) 


search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1")
search_button.click()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver.page_source
doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
rows = doc.find('table', border='.5').find_all('td', attrs={'class': None})

works = []
print(works)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try read_html pandas function by passing the source code once table is loaded:

```py
time.sleep(5) 

# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
# rows = doc.find('table', {"border":'.5'}).find_all('td', attrs={'class': None})
# print(rows[:10])

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 1):

works fine with below adjustments :
1- Add sleep time of 5 sec before trying to read table to give it some time to load.
2- Passing the parameter as dictionnary in doc.find function

```py
time.sleep(5) 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
rows = doc.find('table', {"border":'.5'}).find_all('td', attrs={'class': None})

print(rows[:10])
```

Output:

```py
[<td align="center" width="2%">
<b>SNo.</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>District Name</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Block Name</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Panchayat Name</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Work Start Fin Year</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Work Status</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Work Code</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Work Name</b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Master Work Category Name </b>
</td>, <td align="center">
<b>Work Category Name </b>
</td>]
```

Comment: It is working well :) But i don't know how to print the whole table like this.. I can increase the number of rows. But how do I print the whole table without specifying the number of rows? What i actually want is to put the scraped data in a dataframe and then save it to excel. so instead of print(rows[:10]) is there a way to convert the whole scraped table to a df. It would be of immense help if you could look into it and give an answer.

Comment: update ..i found how to write it to df... But thanks a lot for your initial help anyway

Comment: You are welcome. You may consider accepting the answer then.

Comment: Sure.. I did... Thanks